# Facebook Permission errors when adding agency

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having an issue programmatically giving my business access to facebook pages of users on my app.

When a user logs into our application we request the following scopes: *business_management, manage_pages, pages_show_list, publish_pages, pages_manage_posts, pages_manage_ads, pages_manage_metadata*

After that we show an option to our users where they can give us permission to their facebook page so we can place ads, posts etc with our business systemuser.

The flow is a follows:

- Retrieve facebook page token
- Add our business as agency to the page with the ADVERTISE and ANALYSE tasks
- Add our business system user to the page as assigned user with the ADVERTISE and ANALYSE tasks

For someone reason we are not allowed to add ourselves to the page in some situations. For some pages we get one of these errors:

`type: OAuthException, code: 200, message: (#200) Permissions error, x-fb-trace-id: GoxbeoEWzwB [HTTP 403]`

`Type OAuthException, code 10, message: (#10) You do not have permission to perform this action. This action requires that you can MANAGE_PERMISSIONS on a managing business account. Or it requires that you can ADMINISTER on this object.`

What am I missing here? The logged in user with the page token has PAGE_MANAGE rights. But for some reason we are unable to add our system user as user to the page

Comment: same problem here - did you come up with a solution yet?

Comment: yeah, ends up we did it wrong. We now use user tokens & page tokens to perform actions instead of trying to assign everything to our system user